# Making a matrix out of rows that are passed through a list that makes rows Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Here is the problem:

> Using the function `row_func()`, create a function `design_matrix()` which takes
>   as input an integer `n`, and returns the `NumPy` array whose `j`th row is
>
> ```
> [1, np.cos(t_j), np.sin(t_j), ... , np.cos(n*t_j), np.sin(n*t_j)]
> ```
>
> where `t_j` is the `j`th time value in `T`. In other words, `design_matrix(n)` should produce a matrix whose `j`th row is `row_func(t_j, n)`.

Here is `row_func()`; I made this first and tested to make sure it worked.

```
def row_func(t,n):
    L = [f for k in range(1,n+1) for f in [np.cos(t*k), np.sin(t*k)]]
    L.insert(0,1)
    return L
```

This code gives me a row of numbers, based on the function

```
[1, cos(t), sin(t), cos(2*t), sin(2*t) , ... , cos(n*t), sin(n*t)]
```

`T` is also a row of 291 numbers that I've imported in.

`design_matrix(10).shape` should return a value of `(629, 21)` and `design_matrix(4)[100,:]` should return the row

```
array([ 1. , 0.54030231, 0.84147098, -0.41614684, 0.90929743,
  -0.9899925 , 0.14112001, -0.65364362, -0.7568025 ])
```

Here's what I've tried: Because I'm trying to get the `j`th time value in the array `T`, it should be as simple as replacing `t` for `T` in my function, right?

```
def design_matrix(n):
    X_matrix = np.array(row_func(T,n))
    return X_matrix
```

`row_func()` should grab the values of `t` and compute them in a row. However, I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence as an error.
```

So my question is, how do I build a matrix out of a row/column and a function that builds rows for me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'build a matrix out of a row'? If you have already captured the row you want then it depends on its format. If the row is a pandas series (say s), then you can simply use s.values. What do you mean by 'builds rows for me'? Build it it from individual cells?

Comment: So row_func builds a row [1,cos(t),sin(t), cos(2*t), sin(2*t) , ... , cos(nt), sin(nt)], and I need to build a matrix out of [1,np.cos(t_j),np.sin(t_j), ... ,np.cos(nt_j),np.sin(nt_j)], where T is a row itself. So essentially, this should build a matrix, 291 rows tall, and 2n+1 columns wide (because row function runs sin, cos, and then I inserted 1 at the beginning)

Comment: @bartcubrich Sorry, I don't know if my previous comment made sense. Essentially, I need row_func to run it's function in a row (or each value in the T vector/array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [`numpy.stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).

```
def design_matrix(n):
    row_list = []
    for t in T:
        row_list.append(
            np.array(row_func(t, n)))

    return np.stack(row_list, axis=0)
```

Comment: T is an array of 691 values. 

When I try design_matrix(4)[100,:], I get index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4. It seems that it's not building the right row size? Is that a problem with the initial for loop? Should it be T.size?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Ah, the number of rows should be fixed, ok. I edited my answer

Comment: that looks like it works! Thanks for your help! I'll accept it when I can. It looks like stacking worked.